# Using cURL to upload POST data with files

Tags: shell, file, curl, post, file-upload

I would like to use cURL to not only send data parameters in HTTP POST but to also upload files with specific form name. How should I go about doing that ?

HTTP Post parameters:

userid = 12345
filecomment = This is an image file

HTTP File upload:
File location = /home/user1/Desktop/test.jpg
Form name for file = image (correspond to the $_FILES['image'] at the PHP side)

I figured part of the cURL command as follows:

```
curl -d "userid=1&filecomment=This is an image file" --data-binary @"/home/user1/Desktop/test.jpg" localhost/uploader.php
```

The problem I am getting is as follows:

```
Notice: Undefined index: image in /var/www/uploader.php
```

The problem is I am using $_FILES['image'] to pick up files in the PHP script.

How do I adjust my cURL commands accordingly ?

Answer (score 834, accepted):

You need to use the `-F` option:
`-F/--form <name=content> Specify HTTP multipart POST data (H)`

Try this:

```
curl \
  -F "userid=1" \
  -F "filecomment=This is an image file" \
  -F "image=@/home/user1/Desktop/test.jpg" \
  localhost/uploader.php
```

Comment: I'm confused by the part about url-encoding the file. I have uploaded JPG and PNG files like this without modifying them, without any problems.

Comment: @DavidGelbart You're right. My initial answer referenced the `-d` option by mistake, which needs the input URL-encoded. I should have removed that when I updated the answer to the `-F` option. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @jimp how do we add multiple files in the curl command for POST

Comment: @user956424 Just repeat the `-F` argument for each file you want to send.

Comment: @user956424 In the example, set "image" to the name of your field. And some languages, such as PHP, will build an array if you specify something like "image[]" for the inputs that need to be grouped together.

Comment: Worked fine with me too.. I need to pass some parameters along with image/video uploaded

Comment: I can confirm this is working fine with a Java spring boot backend! thanks you.

Comment: What is the `@` in `image=@/..`?

Comment: @Timo It means the content for the named form field should be loaded from a file path. Without it the string argument itself is passed through.

Comment: how to make an array these kind of post data?

Comment: @muneeb_ahmed, you can just repeat -F "image=@/somefilepath.jpg/" for each file.

Answer (score 151):

Catching the user id as path variable (recommended):

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
-F "data=@test.mp3" http://mysuperserver/media/1234/upload/
```

Catching the user id as part of the form:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
-F "data=@test.mp3;userid=1234" http://mysuperserver/media/upload/
```

or:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
-F "data=@test.mp3" -F "userid=1234" http://mysuperserver/media/upload/
```

Comment: use -F needn't  set ```"Content-Type: multipart/form-data"```

Comment: I couldn't get -F to work properly with that semicolon separator you indicated. Instead, I had to provide two redundant -F arguments. Like: -F "data=@test.mp3" -F "userid=1234"

Answer (score 26):

if you are uploading binary file such as csv, use below format to upload file

```
curl -X POST \
    'http://localhost:8080/workers' \
    -H 'authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6ImFjY2VzcyIsInR5cGUiOiJhY2Nlc3MifQ.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEsImFjY291bnRJZCI6MSwiaWF0IjoxNTExMzMwMzg5LCJleHAiOjE1MTM5MjIzODksImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8veW91cmRvbWFpbi5jb20iLCJpc3MiOiJmZWF0aGVycyIsInN1YiI6ImFub255bW91cyJ9.HWk7qJ0uK6SEi8qSeeB6-TGslDlZOTpG51U6kVi8nYc' \
    -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --data-binary '@/home/limitless/Downloads/iRoute Masters - Workers.csv'
```

Comment: I would like to see an example of a binary csv file.

Comment: @polis the option `--data-binary` instructs `curl` to _not_ do any pre-processing of the data, as opposed to `--data` flag. to address your comment directly, note that text is also binary, but we can interpret it as ASCII characters. If you really want a distinct example, think about a CSV whose fields contain emoji. Their bytes do not directly map to text

Comment: if anyone is googling: `--data-binary` works on AzureBlob direct upload url https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Put-Blob?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: All data in a (typical) computer is binary. ASCII and UTF-8 are binary encodings for text data

Comment: @polis What is a binary csv file?

Comment: What's more disturbing is that existence of binary CSV file implies existence of non-binary CSV file...

Answer (score 24):

Here is my solution, I have been reading a lot of posts and they were really helpful. Finally I wrote some code for small files, with cURL and PHP that I think its really useful.

```
public function postFile()
{    
        $file_url = "test.txt";  //here is the file route, in this case is on same directory but you can set URL too like "http://examplewebsite.com/test.txt"
        $eol = "\r\n"; //default line-break for mime type
        $BOUNDARY = md5(time()); //random boundaryid, is a separator for each param on my post curl function
        $BODY=""; //init my curl body
        $BODY.= '--'.$BOUNDARY. $eol; //start param header
        $BODY .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="sometext"' . $eol . $eol; // last Content with 2 $eol, in this case is only 1 content.
        $BODY .= "Some Data" . $eol;//param data in this case is a simple post data and 1 $eol for the end of the data
        $BODY.= '--'.$BOUNDARY. $eol; // start 2nd param,
        $BODY.= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="somefile"; filename="test.txt"'. $eol ; //first Content data for post file, remember you only put 1 when you are going to add more Contents, and 2 on the last, to close the Content Instance
        $BODY.= 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' . $eol; //Same before row
        $BODY.= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . $eol . $eol; // we put the last Content and 2 $eol,
        $BODY.= chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file_url))) . $eol; // we write the Base64 File Content and the $eol to finish the data,
        $BODY.= '--'.$BOUNDARY .'--' . $eol. $eol; // we close the param and the post width "--" and 2 $eol at the end of our boundary header.



        $ch = curl_init(); //init curl
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                         'X_PARAM_TOKEN : 71e2cb8b-42b7-4bf0-b2e8-53fbd2f578f9' //custom header for my api validation you can get it from $_SERVER["HTTP_X_PARAM_TOKEN"] variable
                         ,"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=".$BOUNDARY) //setting our mime type for make it work on $_FILE variable
                    );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/1.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0'); //setting our user agent
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "api.endpoint.post"); //setting our api post url
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $BOUNDARY.'.txt'); //saving cookies just in case we want
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // call return content
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); navigate the endpoint
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); //set as post
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $BODY); // set our $BODY 


        $response = curl_exec($ch); // start curl navigation

     print_r($response); //print response

}
```

With this we should be get on the "api.endpoint.post" the following vars posted. You can easily test with this script, and you should be receive this debugs on the function `postFile()` at the last row.

```
print_r($response); //print response

public function getPostFile()
{

    echo "\n\n_SERVER\n";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_SERVER['HTTP_X_PARAM_TOKEN']);
    echo "/<pre>";
    echo "_POST\n";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST['sometext']);
    echo "/<pre>";
    echo "_FILES\n";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILEST['somefile']);
    echo "/<pre>";
}
```

It should work well, they may be better solutions but this works and is really helpful to understand how the Boundary and multipart/from-data mime works on PHP and cURL library.

Comment: if you need to send not-encoded file change this lines

      $BODY.= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: multipart/form-data' . $eol . $eol; // we put the last Content and 2 $eol,
      $BODY.= file_get_contents($file_url) . $eol; // we write the Base64 File Content and the $eol to finish the data,

Answer (score 13):

After a lot of tries this command worked for me:

```
curl -v -F filename=image.jpg -F upload=@image.jpg http://localhost:8080/api/upload
```

Answer (score 9):

The issue that lead me here turned out to be a basic user error - I wasn't including the `@` sign in the path of the file and so curl was posting the path/name of the file rather than the contents. The `Content-Length` value was therefore 8 rather than the 479 I expected to see given the legnth of my test file.

The `Content-Length` header will be automatically calculated when curl reads and posts the file.

`curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/xml" --data "@test.xml" -v -X POST https://<url>/<uri/`

...
< Content-Length: 479
...

Posting this here to assist other newbies in future.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to `curl`, you can use [HTTPie](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie#file-upload-forms), it'a CLI, cURL-like tool for humans.

1. Installation instructions: https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie#installation
2. Then, run:

   ```
   http -f POST http://localhost:4040/api/users username=johnsnow photo@images/avatar.jpg

   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-Frontend
   Cache-control: no-store
   Connection: keep-alive
   Content-Encoding: gzip
   Content-Length: 89
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
   Date: Tue, 26 Jun 2018 11:11:55 GMT
   Pragma: no-cache
   Server: Apache
   Vary: Accept-Encoding
   X-Frontend: front623311

   ...
   ```

Answer (score 4):

```
cat test.txt
```

file test.txt content.

```
curl -v -F "hello=word" -F "file=@test.txt" https://httpbin.org/post

> POST /post HTTP/2
> Host: httpbin.org
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
> content-length: 307
> content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------78a9f655d8c87a53
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Mon, 15 Nov 2021 06:18:47 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 510
< server: gunicorn/19.9.0
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< access-control-allow-credentials: true
< 
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {
    "file": "file test.txt content.\n"
  }, 
  "form": {
    "hello": "word"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Content-Length": "307", 
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------78a9f655d8c87a53", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.68.0", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-6191fbc7-6c68fead194d943d07148860"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "43.129.xx.xxx", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Comment: From the entire page of answers, this is the only answer that works for me. 
`-F "file=@test.txt"`. On the backend,  FastAPI expects a `request.filename` property in the request object, I still need to use `file=@...` in the `curl` request (because that is usually expected by the standard endpoint FastAPI function).

Answer (score 3):

I got it worked with this command `curl -F 'filename=@/home/yourhomedirextory/file.txt' http://yourserver/upload`

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to correctly escape arbitrary filenames of uploaded files with `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

f="$1"
f=${f//\\/\\\\}
f=${f//\"/\\\"}
f=${f//;/\\;}

curl --silent --form "uploaded=@\"$f\"" "$2"
```

Answer (score 2):

save all sent files to folder:
php file on host. u.php:

```
<?php
$uploaddir = 'C:/VALID_DIR/';
 echo '<pre>';
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $file) {
    if(!isset($file) || !isset($file['name'])) continue;
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($file['name']);
   
    if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "$key file > $uploadfile .\n";
    } else {
        echo " Error $key  file.\n";
    }
}
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";?>
```

Usage from client:

```
curl -v -F filename=ff.xml -F upload=@ff.xml https://myhost.com/u.php
```

This is worked for me.

My VM crashed it has only internet connection.
I recovered some files this way.