# python 3 tornados file body with headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado, python-requests

I'm tying to write some simple app on python3 and tornado for server, and requests for client, and I'm getting some headers in 'self.request.body', which I can't dispose of. For instance, for file 'blahblahblah', I get:

`--cb5f6ba84bdf42d382dfd3204f6307c7\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.bin"\r\n\r\nblahblahblah\n\r\n--cb5f6ba84bdf42d382dfd3204f6307c7--\r\n`

Files are sent by

```
f = {'file': open(FILE, 'rb')}
requests.post(URL_UPLOAD, files=f)
```

and received by

```
class UploadHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self, filename):
        with open(Dir + filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(self.request.body)
```

My full code can be seen [here](https://github.com/loqutus/blah2%20%5B-%5D)

When I send the file by curl with `curl -X POST -d $(cat ./1.bin) http://localhost:8080/upload/1.bin` I get the correct file, but without \n.

There must be something I missed. Please can someone help me with that? Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to upload files: simply using the file as the request body (usually, but not necessarily, with the HTTP PUT method), or using a multipart wrapper (usually with the HTTP POST method).  If you upload the file from an HTML form, it will usually use the multipart wrapper.  Your requests example is using a multipart wrapper and the curl one is not; your server is not expecting the wrapper.

To use a multipart wrapper: in requests, pass `files=` as you've done here.  With curl, see this answer: [Using curl to upload POST data with files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files).  On the server, use `self.request.files` instead of `self.request.body`: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html#tornado.httpserver.HTTPRequest.files

To *not* use the multipart wrapper, use `data=open(FILE, 'rb').read()` from requests, and keep the other two components the same.

It is possible to support both styles simultaneously on the server: use `self.requests.files` when `self.request.headers['Content-Type'] == 'multipart/form-data'` and `self.request.body` otherwise.