# Get $_FILES from curl without HTML form

Tags: php, curl

If someone were to upload an image via a form:

```
<form method="post" accept="image/*" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input size="28" name="image_upload" type="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In PHP you can get the uploaded `image_upload` via `$_FILES` variable:

```
if(isset($_FILES['image_upload']))
     var_dump($_FILES['image_upload'])
```

And you can proceed to do things with it, such as show the `tmp_name` and can `move_uploaded_file`.

How do I allow someone to upload an image if they were to use CURL, like this, but without the form?

```
   $POST_DATA = array(
    'ImageData' => file_get_contents('image.jpg'),
    );
    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/?image');
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'image={$POST_DATA['ImageData']}');
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_close($handle);
```

Then in the page in which I  receive the curl request...

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['image']))
    var_dump($_FILES); // won't work because i can't get $_FILES from $_POST['image']
var_dump($_POST['image']) // will only show the image data.. i want it to show what the $_FILES variable would normally show.
```

Comment: PHP has no concept of what method was used to send the data to the server. The PHP should be exactly the same.

Comment: Or are you wondering how to do it with curl? If so, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answered right in the php documents ... Example #2 (http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

```
<?php

/* http://localhost/upload.php:
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
*/

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/user/test.png');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Herp de derp...didnt know it was that easy. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I beleive cURL can POST files like this:

```
$post = array('file_contents'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
```

I've tested this a lot of times, always worked for me. Full code would be:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://www.somerandomurl.com/test.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('file_contents'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $result;
```