# cURL - URL containing parameters

Tags: url, curl

I am trying to post a file to webservice with curl and with a content type of "multipart/form-data" and can't get it working. I guess my my problem is that I have parameters in the url.

../fileuploader.ws?aId=579&eId=226

```
curl -u user:password -F -binary-data=@test.pdf "http://localhost/fileuploader.ws?aId=579&eId=226"
```

I am getting error that my request is missing parameters aId and eId. I have also tried with single quotes with the same result. All the topics and discussions says that using quotes should work, but it seems like using quotes with url doesn't have effect.

Comment: If your webservice expects POST parameters, putting them in URL (which are GET parameters) won't do you any good. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files

Answer (score 0):

The behavior depends on your shell envt. Try to escape & with \&  with/without the quotes (single or double)