# Upload multiple files in body request POST to Spring Restful API

Tags: java, spring, rest, curl

I'm construct an uploading multiple images API by Spring Restful. This is my API method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = GiftURI.TEST_UPLOAD, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public 
    @ResponseBody String testUploadMultipleFiles(@RequestBody TestUploadImageReq request) throws BusinessException {
        String fileName = "test";
        String filePath = "/Users/Dona/Desktop/";
        System.out.println("My name is " + request.getMyName());
        for (int i = 0; i < request.getImages().length; i++){
            if (!request.getImages()[i].isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    File newfile = new File(filePath+fileName+i+".jpg");
                    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(newfile, request.getImages()[i].getBytes());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return "You failed to upload cause: " + e.toString();
                }
            }
        }
        return "Finished";
    }
```

This is my TestUploadImageReq model:

```
public class TestUploadImageReq implements Serializable  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5284757625916162700L;
    public TestUploadImageReq(){}

    private MultipartFile[] images;
    private String myName;

    public String getMyName() {
        return myName;
    }

    public void setMyName(String myName) {
        this.myName = myName;
    }

    public MultipartFile[] getImages() {
        return images;
    }
    public void setImages(MultipartFile[] images) {
        this.images = images;
    }

}
```

However, when I used CURL command to test this API, I received the error "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.". This is my CURL command:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:9190/rest/gift/test_upload -d '{"myName":"Dona", "image":"@/Users/Dona/Desktop/mcdona2.jpg"}'
```

How can I test my API by curl command to upload multiple images to the server ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you need your files to be sent to server in JSON format?


Here is an example, how you supposed to be doing it: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

Answer (score 3):

Why standard way, does not work for you?
http://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name,
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
...
```

And you should be able to test it with

```
curl -F "userid=1" -F "filecomment=This is an image file" -F "image=@/home/user1/Desktop/test.jpg" localhost:8080/upload
```

[Using curl to upload POST data with files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files)

If you need more meta, you can add Cookies to your upload Controller

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadWithMetaController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(
         @RequestParam("name") String name,
         @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
         @CookieValue(value = "META", defaultValue = "no") String metaCookie){
...
```

And CURL will look something like this:

```
curl --cookie "META=Yes" -F "userid=1" -F "filecomment=This is an image file" -F "image=@/home/user1/Desktop/test.jpg" localhost:8080/upload
```

Comment: Your suggest is ok. However, what if the TestUploadImageReq has a lot of attributes. Is Using RequestParam a good idea ?

Comment: You can use cookies to specify extra attributes, if you want.

Comment: Could you give an example about using cookies in this case, pls ? Thanks @mavarazy

Comment: Using RequestBody, I can pass objects to TestUploadImageReq model. How can I do it when using RequestParameter ? @mavarazy

Comment: You can create TestUploadImageReq with provided parameters

Comment: Ok, but how can I use CURL command to send both list images and objects ? Can you give an example please ?