# Unexpected image content in RequestHandler.request.arguments.items()

Tags: python, curl, httpwebrequest, tornado

Im currently experiencing a bug caused by not attaching the header `Content-Type` in a curl request.

With a correct request

`curl -v -XPOST -H'Content-Type: image/png' -d@image.png "localhost:9000"`

The `RequestHandler.request.arguments.items()` is a clean list `[]`

However, if I remove the `-H'Content-Type: image/png'` header, and just do something like:

`curl -v -XPOST -d@image.png "localhost:9000"`

`arguments.items()` will be come completely messed up - it now contains a list of random unicodes that looks kind of like this:

```
[('', ['\x19\xf4cX0\xd4A\x86\xd2\x90\x0e\xcf\xa9p\xe5\x82:\x8c\xa8VJz\xc4\xd8Pa\xbfr\xb9`\xc7\xa4\xa8\x90<\xb5\xe3\xd4\x15\xb8\xb9\xfec.*\xff\xd7\xe0rb\xae\x16\x9a\xf5\x08\x9e\xc5\x7f\xd0\x8b\xdf\x9d\x0fQ2, ......
```

Which I assume to be the content of the image I've attached.

How can I resolve this problem? Is there certain flag/function/etc that I can use inside tornado that would prevent the data from being lost? Or do I have to make the user to include the `'Content-Type'` header?

EDIT:

Sorry that I didn't make this clearer earlier, I want to extract the stuff inside `RequestHandler.request.arguments.items()`, which may contains some values that I need.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to upload the image to the website. `Content-type` is not necessary. You need to send [HTTP Multipart Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request).

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files), you need to use `-F` to send multipart data:

```
curl -F "image=@/home/user1/Desktop/test.jpg" "localhost:9000"
```

As for `tornado` part, you can use `self.request.files` to access the file uploaded. Here's an [example](https://technobeans.wordpress.com/2012/09/17/tornado-file-uploads/).

Answer (score 0):

`request.arguments` is for HTML form arguments. When you use `-d@image.png`, the data is sent not as form arguments but as a raw body, so you need to read it from `request.body` instead. This is normally done with method `PUT` instead of `POST`.

Alternately, you can change the request to use a multipart form wrapper as in @skyline75489's answer, and read the image from `request.files`.