# receiving binary file sent through CURL

Tags: php, linux, file, curl

What I'm trying to do is save the binary file sent through CURL from another server.

The php uploader I have is:

```
<?php
define("UPLOAD_DIR", "/tmp/");

if (!empty($_FILES["myFile"])) {
    $myFile = $_FILES["myFile"];

    if ($myFile["error"] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        echo "<p>An error occurred.</p>";
        exit;
    }

    // ensure a safe filename
    $name = preg_replace("/[^A-Z0-9._-]/i", "_", $myFile["name"]);

    // don't overwrite an existing file
    $i = 0;
    $parts = pathinfo($name);
    while (file_exists(UPLOAD_DIR . $name)) {
        $i++;
        $name = $parts["filename"] . "-" . $i . "." . $parts["extension"];
    }

    // preserve file from temporary directory
    $success = move_uploaded_file($myFile["tmp_name"],
        UPLOAD_DIR . $name);
    if (!$success) { 
        echo "<p>Unable to save file.</p>";
        exit;
    }

    // set proper permissions on the new file
    chmod(UPLOAD_DIR . $name, 0644);
}
```

So i have this on my site as such:

example.com/uploader.php

On server number 2, I run the command:

```
curl --request POST  --data-binary "@binary.jpg"  http://example.com/uploader.php
```

and then I check my /tmp/ folder for the file named binary.jpg but it is not there, what is the issue here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files ?

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette No.

Comment: Can you try the curl command suggested in that post to see if your uploader works?

Comment: @NicolasBouvrette It does not work.

Comment: Can you try to replace your upload PHP code with the first example here and see if you get any errors when trying to upload? : http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php (copy/paste the example on top with 221 votes) - this could be a PHP setting playing tricks on you.

Answer (score 0):

It may at location where you run curl command. For example if you run at /home/student then binary. Jpg is at the location /home/student/binary. Jpg 
After running curl command, are you getting successful transfer message?

Answer (score 0):

In the code, `if (!empty($_FILES["myFile"])) {` , you are specifically checking field named `myFile` of array `$_FILES` and then doing stuff. While the `curl` command does not suggest that the binary file is being sent with name `myFile`. You can sepcify the name of the `POST` fields in you `curl` command and issue will be resolved hopefully. (Also try printing the whole `$_POST` and `$_FILES` array in code for debugging purposes)

Comment: How exactly would that be ? Like this? curl --request POST  --data-binary "myFile=@binary.jpg"  http://example.com/uploader.php

Comment: I did curl --request POST --data-binary myFile@binary.jpg http://example.com/uploader.php , no result. This is so frustrating, it must be so simple ?