# PHP and CURL multipart/related

Tags: php, bash, curl

I'm trying to take a picture with a smartphone and send it to a OCR-Server.
I'm now having problem to post the picture with php to the Open-OCR server

Open-OCR provides a sample file howto upload local files to the server.
https://github.com/tleyden/open-ocr/blob/master/docs/upload-local-file.sh

The bash curl command that will be generated looks like this.

```
curl -v -X POST http://192.168.0.107:9292/ocr-file-upload --header 'Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="2ac80ee2f500dbe0bae6d3148fe4f960"' --data-binary @-
```

How can I convert this command to PHP?

I'm really a noob in WEB-Dev and would really appreciate a sample php code that will imitate that command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files

Comment: i dont get it...
i need a PHP command. the link you posted seems to be discussing a Bash command

Comment: http://docs.openocr.apiary.io/#reference/openocr/ocr-decode-via-url/ocr-decode

Comment: this link have php code answers too