# Upload video via Vid.me API

Tags: postman

I faced with problem in Vid.me API more precisely with method Video - Upload in doc https://docs.vid.me/#api-Video-Upload i try to send request in Postman for testing service but always get an error no_file, how should I configurate the request ?

Thx.

Comment: Hi, can you tell us what did you send using postman? Which parameters, etc. because it seems like you don't send any file.

Comment: thank you for reply, I'm already figured out, I just need to use form-data mode

Comment: Ok good luck then! I'll post an answer so you can resolve the thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [vid.me's documentation](https://docs.vid.me/#api-Video-Upload), you need to use `-F` with curl which corresponds to `form-data` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12667839/5179678) for more informations)
You can then find the corresponding with postman.