# how to upload files with angular using CORS

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, restangular, angular1.6

I'm using restangular 1.51 with angular 1.6. My html looks like this

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

and the angular code (based on the discussion [here](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)):

```
let directive = {
  ..
  link: (scope, element, attrs) => {
        let inputElement = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('input'));
        inputElement.bind('change', function () {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', inputElement[0].files[0]);

        API.all('stores/csv').withHttpConfig({transformRequest: angular.identity})             .customPOST(formData,'' , undefined,
          { 'Content-Type': undefined }).then((response) => {console.log(response);
          });
    });
```

laravel code:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => 'required',
        'type'  => 'in:csv,xls,xlsx',
        ]);

    $file = $request->file('file');
    var_dump($file);
    return response()->success(['file' => $file]);
}
```

thing is the $file here is appearing as an empty array in the laravel dump. The documentation is pretty bad on this. Ideas?

## update

It works just fine using postman. this is the curl generated by postman:

**postman curl:**

```
curl -X POST \
  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stores/csv \
  -H 'Accept: application/x.toters.v1+json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ***' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 4f9d2f3b-551b-aa47-4f65-98c7582f2919' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F file=@/Users/Shared/Download/bac-383-store-update.csv
```

**postman server logs**

```
[2018-03-03 06:35:18] local.INFO: ----------------------------- [] []
[2018-03-03 06:35:18] local.INFO: POST api/stores/csv [] []
[2018-03-03 06:35:18] local.INFO: array (   'file' =>    Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile::__set_state(array(      'test' => false,      'originalName' => 'bac-383-store-update.csv',      'mimeType' => 'text/csv',      'size' => 62,      'error' => 0,   )), ) [] []
[2018-03-03 06:35:18] local.INFO: Status code: 200 [] []
[2018-03-03 06:35:18] local.INFO: User id: 104 [] []
```

---

this is the curl generated by restangular

**restangular (two requests - using chrome) curl:**

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stores/csv' 
-X OPTIONS 
-H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: POST' 
-H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' 
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' 
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36' 
-H 'Accept: */*' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
-H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type' 
--compressed


curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stores/csv' 
-H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' 
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' 
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' 
-H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEwNCwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvMTkyLjE2OC4wLjIzMjo4MDAwXC9hcGlcL3VzZXJzXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTUxOTk2OTAzNiwiZXhwIjoxNjE0NTc3MDM2LCJuYmYiOjE1MTk5NjkwMzYsImp0aSI6IndHV0UzRjhYQ3hRdDBGOWMifQ.XqySEIprbxtAU-RfhOgtFkScN1nUuuXEwMxCltfjqu8' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
-H 'Accept: application/x.toters.v1+json' 
-H 'Referer: http://localhost:3000/?local/' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
--data-binary $'------WebKitFormBoundary9ApCHw2ykmLYK2IY\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="bac-383-store-update.csv"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary9ApCHw2ykmLYK2IY--\r\n' --compressed
```

**restangular/chrome server logs**

```
[2018-03-03 06:34:52] local.INFO: ----------------------------- [] []
[2018-03-03 06:34:52] local.INFO: OPTIONS api/stores/csv [] []
[2018-03-03 06:34:52] local.INFO: array ( ) [] []
[2018-03-03 06:34:52] local.INFO: Status code: 200 [] []
[2018-03-03 06:34:52] local.INFO: ----------------------------- [] []
[2018-03-03 06:34:52] local.INFO: POST api/stores/csv [] []
[2018-03-03 06:34:52] local.INFO: array ( ) [] []
[2018-03-03 06:34:52] local.INFO: Status code: 200 [] []
[2018-03-03 06:34:52] local.INFO: User id: 104 [] []
```

## update 2:

after comparing the headers between both curls, i noticed that the content type was different:

*postman curl snippet*

```
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
```

*restangular curl snippet*

```
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

this was shocking, considering that the rectangular people [PROMISED](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) that by using the above syntax, the content type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`:

> Restangular.all('users')
>             .withHttpConfig({transformRequest: angular.identity})
>             .customPOST(formData, undefined, undefined,
>               { 'Content-Type': undefined }); This basically tells the request to use the Content-Type: multipart/form-data as the header.

so I wrote this:

```
    API.all('stores/csv').withHttpConfig({transformRequest: angular.identity})
    .customPOST(formData, undefined, undefined,
      { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }).then((response) => {console.log(response);
```

this improved things a bit.. compare the two curls now:

**postman**

```
curl -X POST \
  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stores/csv \
  -H 'Accept: application/x.toters.v1+json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ***' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 4f9d2f3b-551b-aa47-4f65-98c7582f2919' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F file=@/Users/Shared/Download/bac-383-store-update.csv
```

**angular**

```
  curl 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stores/csv' 
  -H 'Origin: http://localhost:3000' 
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' 
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' 
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ***
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
  -H 'Accept: application/x.toters.v1+json' 
  -H 'Referer: http://localhost:3000/?local/' 
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.186 Safari/537.36' 
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' 
  --data $'------WebKitFormBoundaryd405EnTxpFJv2GDN\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="bac-383-store-update.csv"\r\nContent-Type: text/csv\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryd405EnTxpFJv2GDN\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n\r\nfile\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryd405EnTxpFJv2GDN--\r\n' 
  --compressed
```

so i'm still not sending the `-F` [option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12667839/766570)

Comment: I'm not sure what arguments `customPOST` takes, but have you tried `customPOST(formData, undefined, undefined, ...)` using `undefined` instead of an empty string, or `'file'` as the second argument? Also, this example may help https://github.com/mgonto/restangular/issues/1169#issuecomment-156360136

Answer (score 3):

I've not touched on restangular before, however in Laravel, when you want to get a file from the request you need to use the `file` method on the request object:

```
$file = $request->file('file');
```

That should give you an instance of `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`

Comment: that didn't make a difference

Answer (score 1):

I haven't delved into restangular a lot but on an HTTP level, I believe you want your `Content-Type` header to be `multipart/form-data`, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If you're curious about the difference, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073451) out.
Since you're sending a file, `multipart/form-data` is what you want.

---

I know you see Postman do:

```
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

But just a few lines under that, it does:

```
-H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary...
```

Comment: What's the difference between upper case and lower case content-type?

Comment: @abbood: Nothing, HTTP headers are case-insensitive  ([Source](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2))

Comment: So then how did it make sense that the same request has two different values for the same header?

Comment: HTTP Requests can have duplicate headers.  
It makes sense for things like `Cache-Control` or `Cookie`, but doesn't much for `Content-Type`. So I'm guessing web servers just handle it by using the last specified value of the header. Not sure why postman is putting the same header twice though here, might be worth a PR to fix it :)