# How to dynamically add engine at runtime in symmetricDS community version

Tags: java, symmetricds

I use SymmetricDS community version to synchronize data between the server and the clients,the properties files of server and client are all in the same server machine /engines folder. Recently I wanted to add a new engine  in running symmetricds. When i  copyed propeties file of the new engine into the server machine /engines folder, the running symmetricds process didn't find it . The new engine didn't run. 
Somebody said that he added new engine after Symmetric DS start using REST API - http://localhost:31415/api/engine/install available with 3.7.21 version,but he didn't show example. The API only supports POST method.If the api could realize adding engine at runtime , how to do it step by step?

Answer (score 0):

Post service expects a file upload. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12667839/32090 that explains how to call a rest service with POST http method uploading a file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do it successfully by REST API.  If i don't want to use rest api,how to realize it? The MX4J ?

Comment: Add the properties file and restart the server

Comment: I want to add engine at runtime,and i wouldn't restart the server. Method else?

Comment: What's the issue with restarting the server?