# Failed to open/read local data from file/application

Tags: powershell, http, curl, post

I was trying to run `curl` command using PowerShell.

below is the `curl` command

```
curl --location --request POST "controller/lttrouter/v1/TestResult/process-data-results/" --form "synthesisreport=@"C:\Users\subu\Desktop\testdemo\SynthesisReport.csv";type=text/csv" --form "createdBy=subu" --form "jiraStoryId=LT1235" --form "jiraTaskId=LT1236" --form "tag=demo-test"
```

Above `curl` is working on the Command Prompt.

I tried below PowerShell code

```
$CurlExecutable = "C:\curl-7.65.1-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe"
$path="C:\Users\subu\Desktop\Test\SynthesisReport.csv"

Write-Host "CurlFile" $CurlFile
$CurlArguments = '--location','--request', 'POST', 
                 '"controller/lttrouter/v1/TestResult/process-data-results/"',
                 '--form', 'synthesisreport=@$path',
                 '--form', 'createdBy=subu',
                 '--form', 'jiraStoryId=LT1235',
                 '--form', 'jiraTaskId=LT1236',
                 '--form', 'tag=demo-test'

& $CurlExecutable @CurlArguments
```

I am getting below error

```
curl.exe : curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application
At line:13 char:1
+ & $CurlExecutable @CurlArguments
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (curl: (26) Fail...ile/application:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Where I am doing the mistake, please suggest.

Comment: PowerShell is not C.. Remove the `@` from the line `'synthesisreport=@$path'` and use double quotes around it instead of single quotes, so the `$path` variable gets expanded.

Comment: Refer to this post [Using curl to upload POST data with files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12667797/6521116)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use splatting in this case, just pass the argument list (`$` instead of `@`), properly add the quotes and make sure $path gets expanded:

```
$curlExecutable = "C:\curl-7.65.1-win64-mingw\bin\curl.exe"
$path = "C:\Users\subu\Desktop\Test\SynthesisReport.csv"

Write-Host "CurlFile" $curlExecutable
$curlArguments = "--location","--request", "POST", 
                 "`"controller/lttrouter/v1/TestResult/process-data-results/`"",
                 "--form", "`"synthesisreport=@`"$path`";type=text/csv`"",
                 "--form", "`"createdBy=subu`"",
                 "--form", "`"jiraStoryId=LT1235`"",
                 "--form", "`"jiraTaskId=LT1236`"",
                 "--form", "`"tag=demo-test`""

& $curlExecutable $curlArguments
```

Comment: I tried the above code still getting the same error. Additionally, I tried verified the `@curlExecutable`    with this code    ` Write-Host @curlArguments`   
`--location --request POST "controller01/lttrouter/v1/TestResult/process-data-results/" --form "synthesisreport="C:\Users\subu\Desktop\Test\SynthesisReport.csv";type=text/csv" --form "createdBy=subu" --form "jiraStoryId=LT1235" --form "jiraTaskId=LT1236" --form "tag=demo-test"`

Comment: Did you change `TestResult` to `Test` on purpose in the path?