# Receive/Send MultiRow data along with file in SpringBoot Controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, file, postman, multipartform-data

[image]I want to receive multi rows in spring boot controller, tried different approached but unable to do it. i am testing with postman.

## Controller

```
@PostMapping(URLConstant.URL_SC_ATTACHMENT_POST)
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> storeFile(@RequestParam("attachmentDto") List<BudgetSceAttachmentDto> attachmentDto) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(attachmentDto);
    return ResponseUtil.getResponse(HttpStatus.OK, MsgConstant.BUDGET_MSG_FILE_UPLOADED, null);

}
```

## DTO

```
private Integer versionId;

private String fileName;

private String pathUploadedFile;

private String uploadedFileName;

private MultipartFile file;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, request's content-type should be `multipart/form-data`.

Then Let's simplify this problem - check upload multiple file first.

```
@PostMapping(URLConstant.URL_SC_ATTACHMENT_POST)
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> storeFile(@RequestParam MultipartFile[] files) throws IOException {
    Assert.isTrue(files.length == 2, "files length should be 2");
    System.out.println(files.length);
    return ResponseUtil.getResponse(HttpStatus.OK, MsgConstant.BUDGET_MSG_FILE_UPLOADED, null);
}
```

If it works well, now time to bring the DTO again.

```
@PostMapping(URLConstant.URL_SC_ATTACHMENT_POST)
public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> storeFile(@ModelAttribute List<BudgetSceAttachmentDto> params) throws IOException {
    Assert.isTrue(params.length == 2, "files length should be 2");
    System.out.println(params.length);
    return ResponseUtil.getResponse(HttpStatus.OK, MsgConstant.BUDGET_MSG_FILE_UPLOADED, null);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input, First approach is working fine, how to send the dto's data from postman, i am trying the same way which i have followed above, Body-> form-data and key value, but however i have DTO at controller so i am not sure how the data should be pass from postman.

Comment: Now I understand your problem is postman. Unfortunatly, I have no idea about postman but why don't you use cURL? It looks old-fashon but simple and reliable. [cURL to upload File](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28045514/1378965) I recommand use cURL to confirm the java code first and try with postman again.