# Curl failed to upload file

Tags: php, forms, file, curl, file-upload

I refer to this post [Using curl to upload POST data with files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12667797/6521116) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12667839/6521116) to upload files.

On Windows,

```
curl -F "file=@‪/c/Users/lf/Desktop/HQ/README" https://example.com/upload
curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application
```

and the curl version,

```
curl -V
curl 7.65.3 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) libcurl/7.65.3 OpenSSL/1.1.1c (Schannel) zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.2.0 nghttp2/1.39.1
Release-Date: 2019-07-19
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz Metalink MultiSSL NTLM SPNEGO SSL SSPI TLS-SRP
```

On Centos, (I also try with sudo without success)

```
curl -F "file=@‪/data/HQ/README" https://example.com/upload
curl: (26) couldn't open file "‪/data/HQ/README"
```

and the curl version,

```
curl -V
curl 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0 NSS/3.36 zlib/1.2.7 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz unix-sockets
```

Comment: You either have no permissions or the path is wrong. Thats what the error sais.

Comment: @DieterKräutl I use sudo, and can vim the file.

Comment: When remove the `=` I get, `curl -F "file@‪/c/Users/lf/Desktop/HQEADME" https://example.com/upload
Warning: Illegally formatted input field!
curl: option -F: is badly used here
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
`

Comment: https://www.dorcode.com/questions/134/how-to-post-file-or-image-using-php-curl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it the following way:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-F "data=@‪/data/HQ/README" http://example.com/upload
```

Comment: I finally find it's  "@‪"  cause the problem. Refer to [ord, md5 shows different behaviour on @](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58010740/6521116)