# ord, md5 shows different behaviour on @

Tags: php, string, char, md5, ord

I used `ord` to check `@` and `@‪` are same char. But `ord` output the same value while `md5` does not.

```
php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo ord('@');
64
php > echo ord('@‪');
64

php > echo md5('@');
518ed29525738cebdac49c49e60ea9d3
php > echo md5('@‪');
e6124653b6620abe51d7c401a7644674
php >
```

Here is the screenshot,
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce that. I always get `518ed29525738cebdac49c49e60ea9d3`

Comment: Something else is going on here. Check for hidden characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second one is `@` followed by `U+202A - LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING`. As they are different strings, naturally they have different MD5 encodings.

```
php > echo md5("@\u{202a}");
e6124653b6620abe51d7c401a7644674
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how'd you figure this out?

Comment: To add: ord does this: `Interprets the binary value of the first byte of string as an unsigned integer between 0 and 255.` so it only looks at the first byte of the string. You will probably get the same result by doing `@sdafaf34we`, which obvioulsy has a different md5 then `@`

Comment: Copy-paste the text from the question into the F12 console, then `Array.from("the string").map(c=>c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16))`

Comment: Man, That's some seriously keen observation.. Thumbs up..!!

Comment: Could you explain why the 16 in the `toString`?

Comment: @Script47 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString seems to be a base conversion so that would mean hexdecimal