# Getting error {"name":"Bad Request","message":"Unsupported image type","code":0,"status":400} while uploading image

Tags: curl, webrequest

I am trying to use curl to upload images on

```
 curl.exe -XPOST  -d "Content-Type: image/jpeg"  'https://mmp.eventgallery.com/api/v1/picture/upload?tag={asd}&collection-url={customUrl}&collection-name={eventName}&collection-date={2018-02-22}&name={download.jpeg}&token=XXXXXX'
```

I am getting below error.

{"name":"Bad Request","message":"Unsupported image type","code":0,"status":400}

I am using the link https://desk.zoho.com/portal/darkroomsoftware/kb/articles/api

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files) post for detailed solution.

Comment: After making the changes i am getting different error now. Now i am getting --  {"name":"Internal Server Error","message":"An internal server error occurred.","code":0,"status":500}   `curl.exe -XPOST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"  -d '@download.jpeg'  "https://app.eventgallery.com/api/v1/picture/upload?tag={asd}&collection-url={testeventfiverr}&collection-name={testeventfiverr}&collection-date={2018-02-23}&name={download.jpeg}&token=XXXXXXX"`