# Couldn't read data from file error on curl POST request

Tags: curl

Can anyone help with this curl request? I've tried it a few different ways but every time it can read the data from the file.  I've done successful curl GET and Post request with the data in the request but I can't get it to read the file.

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://xxxxx' \
--header 'Account-Token: xxxxx' \
--header 'Authorization: Token xxxxxx' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/csv' \
--data-binary '@/C:/Users/xxxx/filename.csv'
```

```
Error:
Warning: Couldn't read data from file
Warning: "/C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/filename.csv", this
Warning: makes an empty POST.
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files

Comment: thanks still have same issue though.  Do you have to do anything with the permissions of the file?

Comment: What do you mean about the permission? If the file could be read that would be fine.

Comment: Is this on Windows? I've never seen a Windows C using that format. Try `C:/Users/...` (no leading slash) for Microsoft, or `/C/Users/...` (no colon) for mingw. Or, first `cd/d c:\Users\...` then use a relative name `--data-binary @filename.csv`

Comment: same issue either way:                                                                                               
... --data-binary @test.csv
{"errors":{"name":["can't be blank"]}}
... --data-binary @C:/Users/unyon/Desktop/curl/test.csv
{"errors":{"name":["can't be blank"]}}