# FastAPI post method ends up giving "Method not allowed"

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to deploy an image classification model on server using FastAPI.

As such, I have two issues related to my code.

The first issue is that in the original code (without using FastAPI), I would read an image using OpenCV and then convert it from BGR to RGB. Not doing this conversion would give me inaccurate results at test time.

Using FastAPI, the image is being read as follows:

```py
def read_image(payload):
    stream=BytesIO(payload)
    image=np.asarray(bytearray(stream.read()),dtype="uint8")
    image=cv2.imdecode(image,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    if isinstance(image,np.ndarray):
        img=Image.fromarray(image)
    return img
```

The second issue I am facing is with the POST method when I run the server, and accessing the URL
`http:127.0.0.1:9999/`, the GET method is running, which prints the following message:

```
Welcome to classification server
```

However, when I execute the post method shown below:

```py
@app.post("/classify/")
async def classify_image(file:UploadFile=File(...)):
    #return "File Uploaded."
    image_byte=await file.read()
    return classify(image_byte)
```

When I go to the link `http:127.0.0.1:9999/classify/` I end up recieving the error:

```
method not allowed
```

Any reasons on why this is happening and what can be done to fix the error?
The full code is listed below. If there are any errors that I am missing in this, please let me know. I am new to FastAPI and as such, I am really confused about this.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File
import uvicorn
import torch
import torchvision
from torchvision import transforms as T
from PIL import Image
from build_effnet import build_model
import torch.nn.functional as F
import io
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np
import cv2

app = FastAPI()

class_name = ['F_AF', 'F_AS', 'F_CA', 'F_LA', 'M_AF', 'M_AS', 'M_CA', 'M_LA']
idx_to_class = {i: j for i, j in enumerate(class_name)}
class_to_idx = {value: key for key, value in idx_to_class.items()}

test_transform = T.Compose([
                             
                             #T.Resize(size=(224,224)), # Resizing the image to be 224 by 224
                             #T.RandomRotation(degrees=(-20,+20)), #NO need for validation
                             T.ToTensor(), #converting the dimension from (height,weight,channel) to (channel,height,weight) convention of PyTorch
                             T.Normalize([0.485,0.456,0.406],[0.229,0.224,0.225]) # Normalize by 3 means 3 StD's of the image net, 3 channels
])

#Load model
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model = build_model()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(
    'CharacterClass_effnet_SGD.pt', map_location='cpu'))
model.eval()
model.to(device)

def read_image(payload):
    stream=BytesIO(payload)
    image=np.asarray(bytearray(stream.read()),dtype="uint8")
    image=cv2.imdecode(image,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    if isinstance(image,np.ndarray):
        img=Image.fromarray(image)
    return img

def classify(payload):
    img=read_image(payload)
    img=test_transform(img)
    with torch.no_grad():
        ps=model(img.unsqueeze(0))
        ps=F.softmax(ps,dim=1)
        topk,topclass=ps.topk(1,dim=1)
    x=topclass.view(-1).cpu().view()
    return idx_to_class[x[0]]
        
@app.get("/")
def get():
    return "Welcome to classification server."

@app.post("/classify/")
async def classify_image(file:UploadFile=File(...)):
    #return "File Uploaded."
    image_byte=await file.read()
    return classify(image_byte)
```

Comment: What do you mean by _when I go to the link_? You open this link in browser?

Comment: yes i am opening the link in browser

Comment: Please have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) (**Method 3** - **Test with Fetch or Axios**) on how to upload a file, as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804) on how to send back a numpy array / image bytes.

Comment: Ok I will @Chris,is it okay to reach out to you if I run into issues.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has defined the classify route on POST requests. Your browser will only perform GET requests from the url

If you expect the browser to work, use `@app.get("/classify/")`. However, you'll need a different way to provide the file argument, which as a query parameter and a file path (not recommended for security reasons).

If you want POST requests to work, test your code with curl or Postman

Comment: i tried doing @app.get("/classify/"),that gives me the following errror
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","file"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
Also,any suggestions on how I can send image to this via curl/postman
let's say my image is img_1.jpg

Comment: I tried using curl -L -F "file=@model_2_0.jpg" http://127.0.0.1:9999/classify/ that ended up giving an internal server error.Any ideas why that happened

Comment: Well, you'd need to look at the logs of the server rather than its response to the client, but you're still using a GET method, there

Comment: I'm not sure what `-F` flag does. Perhaps you wanted `--data` or `-d`?

Comment: I changed the method back to post and then used curl to test the code.
The model's prediction come out to be {},which is strange because when I test the code without fastapi,the prediction usually comes out to be a class

Comment: Sorry, not really sure. Haven't used these prediction libraries, or fastapi, really. This  answer is exclusively for "method not allowed" response

Comment: Don't change `@app.post(...)` to `@app.get(...)`, create another function for that. You have file field required inside post request, so you are asked to pass it

Comment: using the flag --data gives me the following error
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","file"],"msg":"Expected UploadFile, received: <class 'str'>","type":"value_error"}]}

Comment: ok thanks OneCricketeer,atleast now I am able to get something.I just need to look into how to get the correct prediction.If anyone can give anymore suggestions on this that will be helpful

Comment: tried passing the file through curl ,but it seems that the file is not being read because file.filename comes out to be null.
I was passing -L which was causing the issue.

Comment: Reading the Fastapi docs, it expects a form request, and that's what -F flag is for, but you'll also need to add `-X POST` https://stackoverflow.com/a/28045514/2308683